# Possible values for [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];

Tags: ios

What are the possible values of `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];`? In the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) from Apple, it doesn't give any examples of what could result, but all I can get from it is `iPhone OS`, even on the simulator. Are there any other possibilities, and if not, why does this property even exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the operating system's name as the docs say. iOS was initially called "iPhone OS" (before iPad) but I think they didn't changed the `systemName` for compatibility reasons.

In the future, they could implement `[UIDevice systemName]` on (Mac) OS X and on that platform it would probably return `Mac OS X` or `OS X`.

The current use for this method is quite limited but you never know what ((partly) compatible) operating systems Apple or someone else may produce in the future...

Comment: I thought that was the case, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: FYI, on tvOS the `systemName` will be `@"tvOS"`, and on watchOS it will be `"watchOS"` (via `WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().systemName`).

Comment: it does appear this value changes from "iPhone OS" to "iOS" with iOS 10

Answer (score 5):

for iPhone, the value for Operating System returned by Apple has been “iPhone OS”. In certain versions of iOS 9 and for apps published post-Xcode 8 running iOS 10, Apple has replaced the value for “iPhone OS” with “iOS.

Answer (score 2):

after the ios version 15 update ipad os has replace the value for "iOS" to "iPadOS"